# Some examples/tips for making clear about interface and polymorphism

Tags: oop, interface, polymorphism

I read about polymorphism as well as interface but a bit hard to catch them at once. I would like some real life example where they have been implemented.

It would be better if its of vb.net or php, as i am habitual on coding on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interface and polymorphism are not specific to any languages, but concepts used to model the problem and solution space. All the object oriented languages provide a way to achieve or implement code which closely matches theses concepts.

Before looking at what are they? lets briefly look at why you need them? and how they are useful.

Simple example of an interface is "Car" always has same interface Break, Accelerate, once you know how to drive one you can drive any car. Therefore if a person (solution) gets this uniform interface of the car irrespective of make and model he can drive, that is why you can drive almost any car. Same way when you write code to solve one specific class of problem you could reuse the solution against multiple domains or objects which provide similar interface to work with.

Simple example of Polymorphism, look at an Account (it may be checking or saving assuming each attract different dividends) you walk in a bank and ask a teller what is my balance? or dividends? you dont need to specify what kind of an account you're having he will internally figure out looking at his books and provide you the details. Internal details on how the teller works are hidden from you for each case (checking and savings) where as anybody can walk in and ask the question and get the answer suitable to the person in question. So the teller is polymorphic (he's changing his working rules or forms) to suit the customer.

Interfaces like in car example provide a contract to work with objects, as long as you adhere to that contract one set of solutions can be applied to another domain as long as interfaces in question are same. `Interfaces promote reuse of solutions by making them generic.` As long as you have a credit card you can drink beer kinds, you dont need to have special bar for each kind of credit card.

Polymorphism like in Teller Account example would `Promote reuse of interface or messages by reusing same message or interface to provide different but semantically equivalent mechanisms`. You pick up your phone and dial a number irrespective of the destination number being landline or a cellphone or a something else, here the interface of dialing a 10 digit number is reused in each of the mechanisms which are equivalent semantically.

**Now you can go ahead and look up some interfaces in VB.NET or PHP, I'm not very aware of these languages**

Look the way Controls (VB.NET) react to similar methods to see polymorphism in action. For interfaces lookup the objects who implement IEnumerable(from above answer), or ISerializable and objects which implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've used interfaces if you've ever used a `For Each` loop. The compiler knows about the `IEnumerable(Of T)` interface, so it's able to iterate over *any* sequence by calling `GetEnumerator()` to get an `IEnumerator(Of T)`, and then call `MoveNext()` and `Current` repeatedly to read the elements of the sequence. This will work whether you're iterating over a `List(Of T)`, a `LinkedList(Of T)`, a `HashSet(Of T)` or whatever. You can depend on just the interface. LINQ to Objects is based on this too (although with some specific optimizations for other interface types).

For polymorphism, I usually use `Stream` as an example. It's easy to write code which uses any `Stream` and not care about whether it's actually a `FileStream`, a `NetworkStream`, a `MemoryStream` or something else. The stream implementation will override appropriate members to make it "just work".